# Android unit tests with Jenkins on a headless machine

Tags: android, unit-testing, jenkins

I'm gathering information to set up a Jenkins CI server on a headless machine for Android unit testing.
But as Android unit tests require an emulator to run, a graphical environment seems required, or is it possible to run an emulator in non-graphical mode?
The wiki entry on the [Jenkins Android Emulator plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) is also not very enlightening on this matter, it states:

> If you have build slaves running headless (e.g. Linux servers that don't run an X server), it is recommended to take advantage of Jenkins' Xvnc Plugin.
>   With this plugin enabled, you can run multiple Android emulators in parallel on a headless slave, while keeping the "Show emulator window" option enabled.

Does this imply that emulators can be run on a headless machine with the "Show emulator window" option disabled??

If a graphical environment is required the easiest solution most sources speak of is by using the Xvnc plugin which uses an Xvnc server to provide an X instance.
But if I understand correctly this Xvnc server must run on another machine with X available, or does it run on the headless machine providing an X instance from there?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As the author of that plugin, I can tell you yes: you can run emulators on a headless machine, without a graphical environment — just uncheck the "Show emulator window" option.

This is the equivalent of running the Android emulator with the "`-no-window`" option on the command line.

I will update the wiki to make this clearer; thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: No problem; I've improved the wiki documentation now.

Comment: seems to be broken again: Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27594 -- you need to add -no-audio.... it's a bug [tm]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup in my project. But I chose Robolectric for my unit tests.

It is quite easy to run the **Robolectric** tests on Jenkins.

You may have to go for emulator for your system tests on a headless Jenkins server.

I still do not have a solution to run the system tests on a headless server.